# NodeJS CORS preflight Access-Control-Allow-Origin wildcard

Tags: node.js, express, cors, preflight

I cannot figure out why this is failing. I am getting a cors error saying that the preflight request failed because the Access-Control-Allow-Origin is set to wildcard despite me configuring the server to use cors. I used many different options and even set my own custom middleware to put the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in with the domain I need. All requests will come from the same domain that I know so that isn't a problem.

the request is coming from account and is being sent to api (the server)

**versions:**

1. cors: ^2.8.5
2. express: ^4.17.2

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin shouldn't be a wildcard but for some reason it is.

any advice or guidance on how to troubleshoot this will be helpful.

This is my cors config

```
server.use(cors({     
    origin: ["https://account.domain.com", "https://api.domain.com"],     
    credentials: true,     
    preflightContinue: true,     
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204 
}));
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: For starters, change to `preflightContinue: false`.  That option doesn't work the way most people think at first.  When you set it to `true`, then the CORs middleware sets some headers for the pre-flight request, but then leaves the rest of the request to the rest of your request handlers.  If you set it to `false`, then it will directly respond.

Comment: If that isn't enough to make it work, then, there's something else in your pre-flight request that needs a more specific pre-flight response (perhaps some custom headers).  We would need to see the specific request that is causing pre-flight (all the headers, content-type, etc..) to know what else might be needed.  In the future, you can look in the network tab of the Chrome inspector to see EXACTLY what pre-flight request is being sent to the server and exactly what server response is coming back and including that in your question will make it a ton more likely you get a quick answer.

Answer (score -1):

Put this Node.Js native cors settings inside app.js (or server.js) file just above to your initialized routes.

```js
...
app.all('/*', function (req, res, next) {
  // CORS headers
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*.domain.com"); // restrict it to the required domain
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');
  // Set custom headers for CORS
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers, save-path, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization, X-Access-Token, X-Key');
  if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
    res.status(200).end();
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
app.use('/', routes);  // here goes your routes
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I managed to fix the issue turns out it didn't have anything to do with cors. I had a cpanel git repo and cPanel wasn't updating the git repo properly which caused the updates I made to not be pushed and deployed.